# Performance difference between django query and stored procedure (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, stored-procedures

I want to use a query that calculates points that are a D distance away from a point (i.e. geolocation stuff), so the query is somewhat complex:

```
        DELIMITER //

    CREATE PROCEDURE geodist (IN m_lat double, IN m_lng double, IN dist int, IN lim int)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE lon1 double; DECLARE lon2 double;
    DECLARE lat1 double; DECLARE lat2 double;

    -- calculate lon lat for the rectangle
    SET lon1 = m_lon-dist/abs(cos(radians(m_lat))*69);
    SET lon2 = m_lon+dist/abs(cos(radians(m_lat))*69);
    SET lat1 = m_lat-(dist/69); 
    SET lat2 = m_lat+(dist/69);

    -- run query;
    SELECT post.id, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((m_lat - post.geo_lat) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(m_lat * pi()/180) * COS(post.geo_lat * pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((m_lng - post.geo_lng) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance 
    FROM post_post as post
    WHERE
    post.geo_lng BETWEEN lon1 AND lon2
    AND post.geo_lat BETWEEN lat1 AND lat2
    HAVING distance < dist ORDER BY Distance limit lim;

    END //
```

well above is what my stored procedure would be.  Since I will be using this to go through thousands if not millions of rows of data I was wondering what the performance hit on using a django query over a stored procedure would be?  I realize that django doesn't support stored procedures so that's why I was hoping to avoid using stored procedures.  However, then the query won't be compiled in the db and the calculations would have to be done in python ... etc. What's the difference in performance between a django query and a store procedure called from django?

Comment: You asked this question 3 times. This is a crosspost.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]
There is a huge performance improvement if you use specialized database functions like the ones in Postgis or Mysql Spatial Extensions, compared to calculating everything in python.

Take a look at [geodjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/), the setup is somewhat painful but it has everything you may ever need for geolocation.

If geodjango is too much, you can always resort to [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) for this particular query.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use geodjango due to the setup/number of extra components you need and the fact that I really only need this one function to work... I know you're trying to help but please answer the question asked first

Comment: Yes, I realize there is a raw SQL with django and how to use it, wat I'm interested in is the performance difference between executing the raw query from django and a normal django query...

Comment: @Derek: I would say about an order of magnitude if using Postgis or Mysql Spatial Extensions. Otherwise depends more on the database server and web server setups. For millions of records I would keep it at the database layer because the data transfer of the non matching records would be expensive.